# Spring MVC handle button event in list

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i created a list of Users

```
<div class="usersList">           
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <div class="listElementAction">
                <c:out value="${user.id}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="listElement">
                <c:out value="${user.firstName}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="listElement">
                <c:out value="${user.lastName}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="listElement">
                <c:out value="${user.username}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="listElementAction">
                <input type="button" name="Edit" title="Edit" value="Edit" />
            </div>
            <div class="listElementAction">
                <input type="image" src="images/delete.png" name="image" value="${user.id}" alt="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete ${user.username}?')" >
            </div>
            <br />            
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
```

and my controler looks like this

```
public class UsersController implements Controller {

    private UserServiceImplementation userServiceImplementation;

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {        

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users");                
        modelAndView.addObject("users", this.userServiceImplementation.get());
    return modelAndView;

    }

    public UserServiceImplementation getUserServiceImplementation() {
        return userServiceImplementation;
    }

    public void setUserServiceImplementation(UserServiceImplementation userServiceImplementation) {
        this.userServiceImplementation = userServiceImplementation;
    }


}
```

How can i handle the delete and edit button event?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you need a form in your HTML if you don't already have one. That leads neatly on to the next thing, which is that when handling a form in Spring you should use a form controller. The [SimpleFormController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html) is a good starting point. You'll want to read up on them a bit before getting stuck in. [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls4/) is an excellent reference.